# Why certain address shows 00000000

Tags: debugging, ollydbg

```
00000583 : A100000000              MOV eax,dword ptr ds:[00000000]                   
00000588 : 50                      PUSH eax                                          
00000589 : 83EC24                  SUB esp,24                                        
0000058C : 53                      PUSH ebx                                          
0000058D : 56                      PUSH esi                                          
0000058E : 57                      PUSH edi                                          
0000058F : A120798F02              MOV eax,dword ptr ds:[028F7920]                   
00000594 : 33C5                    XOR eax,ebp                                       
00000596 : 50                      PUSH eax                                          
00000597 : 8D45F4                  LEA eax,dword ptr ss:[ebp+F4]                     
0000059A : 64                      fs:                                               
0000059B : A300000000              MOV dword ptr ds:[00000000],eax                   
000005A0 : 894DEC                  MOV dword ptr ss:[ebp+EC],ecx                     
000005A3 : 8B4130                  MOV eax,dword ptr ds:[ecx+30]                     
000005A6 : 8B5138                  MOV edx,dword ptr ds:[ecx+38]                     
000005A9 : 8B493C                  MOV ecx,dword ptr ds:[ecx+3C]
```

I am trying to get all 00000000 back to original anyway please !!

Comment: It seems that these are the offsets given by decoding the opcodes. Why do you think it should something else?

Comment: do you modify your code and you want to remove your changes?